# oocalc plugin - development step by step guide available?

Tags: python, plugins, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I want to develop plugin for OoCalc Open Office,
is there any good resource or link will help to start working on it.

any existing article like step by step guide for developer would be great !!

I want to develop the plugin based on Python Programming Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [OpenOffice.org's extension development](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development) site. This has all the information regarding the development of extensions for openoffice. For how to develop plugin in Python, you can refer to [this](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development_python) link.

Also [Danny's OOo library](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=56015#56015) would be helpful which makes programming OOo in Python much more like programming OOo in Basic.